# Group by in ordered columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here's my query:

```
SELECT p.*,r.* 
FROM products p 
left join p_images r 
  on (p.id=r.product)
```

The result:

```
id | name | img    | nu
25 | shoe | a1.jpg | 1
25 | shoe | a2.jpg | 0
26 | elbs | r3.jpg | 1
```

I want this result

```
shoe a2.jpg 0
elbs r3.jpg 1
```

When I use `group by p.id` in the query, it outputs `a1.jpg`.
I want to order with `min("nu")` columns value.

Comment: Can you add your table structures? I think it's product(id, name), p_images(img, product), but what is nu from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN p_images r ON (r.product=p.id) 
WHERE r.nu = (SELECT MIN(nu) FROM p_images m WHERE m.product = p.id)
ORDER BY nu
```

Comment: You are missing the order by min value in this query.

Comment: thats why MIN(nu) is added in sub query

Comment: But i liked your way of fetching the result in that way

Comment: I get that you are filtering in the where clause for the min value, I am saying that you are missing the order by in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to get the `min(nu)` value and then join that back to your `p_image` table to be sure you are returning the correct image:

```
select p.id,
  p.name,
  i.img,
  r.minnu
from products p 
left join
(
  select min(nu) MinNu, product
  from p_images
  group by product
) r 
  on p.id=r.product
left join p_images i
  on r.minnu = i.nu
  and r.product = i.product
order by i.nu;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99cf8/14)

Result:

```
| ID | NAME |    IMG | MINNU |
------------------------------
| 25 | shoe | a2.jpg |     0 |
| 26 | elbs | r3.jpg |     1 |
```

<strike>You can just add an `ORDER BY` that value. Since you are using an order by clause, then you can either use the alias or you can place the aggregate in it.</strike>

Order by alias:

SELECT p.id, 
      p.name,
      r.img,
      min(r.nu) MinNu
    FROM products p 
    left join p_images r 
      on p.id=r.product
    group by p.id
    order by MinNu

Order by aggregate:

SELECT p.id, 
      p.name,
      r.img,
      min(r.nu) MinNu
    FROM products p 
    left join p_images r 
      on p.id=r.product
    group by p.id
    order by min(r.nu);

See SQL [Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99cf8/2) of both queries

The result is:

| ID | NAME |    IMG | MINNU |
    ------------------------------
    | 25 | shoe | a1.jpg |     0 |
    | 26 | elbs | r3.jpg |     1 |

Comment: not very sure, but OP's expected results seem to show `25, a2.jpg, 0` even I missed that part in my earlier query. So I did another.. do you think it's a typo in OP's question :)

Comment: @bonCodigo I actually missed that.  I have now updated my answer to return the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need? Well wrong here, as I took your earlier produced results as the table.. :)

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82728/2)

```
select id, name, img, 
min(nu)
from t1
group by id
;
```

So I might as well give the answer based on that then:

```
select x.id, x.name, x.img, min(x.nu)
from( 
SELECT p.,r. FROM products p 
left join p_images r 
on (p.id=r.product)) x
group by x.id
order by x.nu

| ID | NAME |    IMG | MIN(NU) |
--------------------------------
| 26 | elbs | r3.jpg |       1 |
| 25 | shoe | a1.jpg |       0 |
```

---

Well your expected results says `r2.jpg and 0`, so I think this is what you would need really.. This time around used the correct tables, thanks to @bluefeet for his sql fiddle.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99cf8/7)

```
select p.id, p.name, x.img, x.mn
from products p
left join (select i.product, i.img, 
           min(i.nu) mn
           from p_images i
           group by i.nu, i.product)
x on p.id = x.product
group by x.product
order by x.mn
;

| ID | NAME |    IMG | MN |
---------------------------
| 25 | shoe | a2.jpg |  0 |
| 26 | elbs | r3.jpg |  1 |
```

Comment: @Halis I just double noticed your expected results, it seems you need `a2.jpg 0`.. for `25`, so check this out please :)